# Daffodil skip optional fields

Tags: parsing, xsd

I have a flat file with fixed length fields.
All data is in one line.
Data object starts with AA and ends with END.
Each object has 3 fields with fixed size (4,5,6) chars in my example.
Between the fields there could be varied length breaks.
How to make xsd to parse it with apache daffodil?

Sample:

`AA111 2222 33333 ENDAA111 4444 55555 END`

This schema lets pars it correctly (when no extra fields, spaces)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dfdl="http://www.ogf.org/dfdl/dfdl-1.0/">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo source="http://www.ogf.org/dfdl/">
            <dfdl:format
                    lengthUnits="characters"
                    representation="text"
                    trailingSkip="0"
                    sequenceKind="ordered"
                    encoding="utf-8"
                    alignment="implicit"
                    initiator=""
                    terminator=""
                    truncateSpecifiedLengthString="no"
                    fillByte="0"
                    initiatedContent="no"
                    leadingSkip="0"
                    encodingErrorPolicy="replace"
                    alignmentUnits="bytes"
                    separator=""
                    separatorSuppressionPolicy="anyEmpty"
                    separatorPosition="infix"
                    ignoreCase="no"
                    outputNewLine="%CR;%LF;"
                    textBidi="no"
                    floating="no"
                    escapeSchemeRef=""
                    emptyValueDelimiterPolicy="initiator"
                    textStringPadCharacter="%SP;"
                    textPadKind="padChar"
                    textTrimKind="padChar"
                    textStringJustification="center"
            />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="ClassA" dfdl:lengthKind="implicit">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence dfdl:sequenceKind="ordered">
                <xs:element name="ClassB" dfdl:initiator="AA" dfdl:lengthKind="delimited" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                            dfdl:occursCountKind="parsed" dfdl:terminator="END">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="F1" type="xs:string" dfdl:lengthKind="pattern"
                                        dfdl:lengthPattern="[\S ]{0,4}" minOccurs="0" dfdl:occursCountKind="implicit"/>
                            <xs:element name="F2" type="xs:string" dfdl:lengthKind="pattern"
                                        dfdl:lengthPattern="[\S ]{0,5}"/>
                            <xs:element name="F3" type="xs:string" dfdl:lengthKind="pattern"
                                        dfdl:lengthPattern="[\S ]{0,6}"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But when I add extra spaces/characters like here, it fails.
I tried with the terminator/initiator but without luck.

```
AA111 2222 33333     ENDAA111 4444 55555 END
```

OR

```
AA111 2222 33333 ENDAA111 4444 55555 xxxxx END
```

Comment: Can you share the output of each?  Also you state that is is a fixed length format, but then you start varying the positions of the fields, which is not fixed length,